# Correct architecture of iOS ViewController loading async (HealthKit) data

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, healthkit, viewwillappear

The code below works 90% of the time but every so often I will return an error (i.e. self.hideAllStackViewsAndShowNoWorkoutsMessage() will get called) even though there are workouts to be loaded.  I think it's a VC lifecycle timing issue but I can't find a flaw in my code?

```
MyViewController {
       override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            loadAndSetWorkout() 
        }



   func loadAndSetWorkout() {
        WorkoutManager.loadMostRecentWorkout { (workout, error) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

                    if let unwrappedWorkout = workout {
                        self.selectedWorkout = unwrappedWorkout
                    } else {
                        if let unwrappedError = error {
                            self.hideAllStackViewsAndShowNoWorkoutsMessage()
                            print("Error in LastWorkoutTVC loadMostRecentWorkout = \(unwrappedError)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }

}








                 class func loadMostRecentWorkout(handler: @escaping (HKWorkout?, WorkoutManagerError?) -> Void) {

        let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .other)
        let sourcePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKSource.default()) //limit query to only this app
        let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [workoutPredicate, sourcePredicate, mostRecentPredicate])

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKObjectType.workoutType(), predicate: compound, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in

            if let unwrappedError = error {
                handler(nil, WorkoutManagerError.generalError(unwrappedError.localizedDescription))
                return //added this return
            }

            guard let samples = samples as? [HKWorkout] else {
                handler(nil, WorkoutManagerError.generalError("no samples in loadMostRecentWorkout"))
                return
            }

            guard let mostRecentWorkout = samples.first else {
                handler(nil, WorkoutManagerError.generalError("no first in samples in loadMostRecentWorkout"))
                return
            }
            handler(mostRecentWorkout, nil)

        }
        HealthStoreSingleton.sharedInstance.healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

Comment: How do you know there were workouts to be loaded? From what I see, your completion handler is always called with one nil value, and one non-nil value. It’s never called with two non-nil values. So if you’re getting an error, it can’t be that self.selectedWorkout has a non-nil value. How were you determining that there were workouts in those cases? Were you printing self.selectedWorkout?

Comment: I noticed there’s a comment “added this return”, so I’m guessing at some point you ran the program without that return, in which case your completion handler would have run twice. The first time it would call your hideAllStackViews() method, and the second time it would assign a non-nil value to self.selectedWorkout, which is the exact problem you’re describing. Are you able to reproduce the problem with that new return statement in there?

Comment: @PeterParker thank you, you may be on to something.  The returns are not new, they've been there for a while yet I only noticed this behavior when I added the `hideAllStackViews` (which is displaying an empty data set).  I think a few years ago I had a problem with completion handlers and starting adding returns like this, is it bad design?  Im testing on my own workout data so I know they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just putting this here to show another design, seeing that I can't put code in a comment.

The semantics of your completion handler related code are essentially this:

If there's at least one sample, give it with no errors.
Otherwise, give an error if we got an error, or give the error that there were no samples.

You have the "no samples" error, so we don't really need the "no first sample" error. It's unnecessary, so we can get rid of that.

A possible refactor might look something like this.

```
// We either give a sample, or some error.

if let samples = samples as? [HKWorkout], let first = samples.first {
    handler(first, nil)
} else {
    handler(nil, .generalError(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no samples"))
}
```

It's the same semantics more clearly expressed.

This isn't an answer, but since your handler will never be given a sample and an error, and you're getting an error when you know you have samples in your own workout data, then maybe the culprit is the predicate / query code?

Comment: Thanks, I agree at this very least this cleans up this function.  Should there be returns after the completion handler is called?

Comment: Also is `viewWillAppear` an appropriate VC lifecycle method to makes this call?  It's a tab bar app so I wanted it to refresh if you were switching in between tabs

Comment: @GarySabo You needed the returns before. But now it’s just an if else statement, so the handler will only ever be called once, so you don’t need any returns. I see no problem at all with using viewWillAppear. But I don’t use the built in tab bar component, so I’m not sure if it gets called multiple times when you switch between tabs.

Comment: Thanks, makes 100% sense, can you also add to your answer how you would handle at the call site as well? Inside the loadWorkouts closure?

Comment: There’s not really anything to change in the closure you pass to loadMostRecentWorkout.

Comment: I changed how I handled it at the call site in the same spirit as your suggestion:  if I have a workout set it, else look for an error...I edited it in my question.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry. Reason I thought I'd leave it was because self.selectedWorkout always got assigned. So if the query was successful, self.selectedWorkout got assigned, and then if a subsequent query gave an error, self.selectedWorkout would get set to nil. In the change you made, if a subsequent query gives an error, self.selectedWorkout doesn't get set to nil, so it retains the old workout and then showNoWorkouts() is called, which I thought was a bit of a mismatch, so I left it.

Comment: oh I see, it "should" only get called once given that its looking for the first workout you have, no matter how many you have there is only 1 first.